# Selenium race condition for dialog closing

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-chromedriver, dialog, integration

I have a dialog opened. On trying to close it, the check for if dialog closed is timing out sometimes.

The dialog opens via transform: scale property of css. So, in the end I'm trying to check for scale(0), but its timing out on random basis.

```
self.wait().until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@class, 'sample-dialog')][contains(@style, 'transform: scale(1)')]")))

self.selenium.find_element_by_class_name("sample-close-button").click()

self.wait().until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@class, 'sample-dialog')][contains(@style, 'transform: scale(0)')]")))
```

The wait function is nothing but WebDriverWait defaulted to 10 secs, while the dialog takes merely 0.2s to close:

```
def wait(self, seconds=10):
    return WebDriverWait(self.selenium, seconds)
```

Comment: Pls post your URL

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.